# Powershell profile script with input parameters

Tags: powershell

My powershell script is accessible from all folders as I inserted its path in the profile (the CurrentUserAllHosts in my case).
Now I want to add input parameters to it. I tried the following:

```
param(
 [Parameter()]
 [string]$Parameter1
     )
write-host "$Parameter1"
```

calling the script (let's name it 'script.ps1') directly in its folder works as expected:

```
PS C:\> .\script.ps1 bla
bla
PS C:\>
```

calling it via the Windows profile doesn't:

```
PS C:\other_path\> script bla

PS C:\other_path\>
```

How can I get my input parameters to work via the profile like they do when calling the script directly? Is that even possible?

Comment: Maybe it's the scope of those parameters when I enter them on the CLI which causes the problem? Altough I didn't get far researching that.

Comment: "[...] as I inserted its path in the profile" - can you show us the relevant part of your profile script?

Comment: A better approach might be to convert the script to a [module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-script-module?view=powershell-7.2) and store it on the standard module path - it should then be loaded when needed without having to involve profiles.

Comment: @boxdog thank you, modules are new to me. For my small and regularily used script the profile will do for now, but I'll probably use a module instead in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to invoke a script file by name alone, create an alias in the profile script:

```
Set-Alias -Name script -Value C:\path\to\script.ps1
```

Comment: Thanks! You found the issue: in my profile file it read:
`function script {C:\path\to\script.ps1}`
which worked just fine until I added the parameters. With the parameters only your suggestion works.

Comment: @user15226715 in that case you'd need to pass the parameter arguments to the inner call: `function script { C:\path\to\script.ps1 @args }`